# Changes in Eclipse do not reflect in Worklight Android Simulator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I make changes to Javascript files in Eclipse the changes are not reflected in the Worklight simulator. I'm using cordova to build to different environments, and everything was working fine yesterday. I've tried stopping and starting the server, rebuilding the project, starting eclipse in -clean mode and a few other standard things and no changes I make at this point will reflect in the simulator. It's as if it's using an old build, but I checked and the buildfile is correct. How can I get my changes to reflect in the simulator again?

Comment: What version of Worklight/MobileFirst are you using? Also, in which folder are you making the changes?

Comment: @MichaelHugney We don't support WL before vs 5.0. Is it possible for you to upgrade to a newer version of WL? See here for more information on using [MobileFirst 7.1](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-up-the-mobilefirst-development-environment/)

Comment: I apologize, I'm using 6.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

These are the release dates of Worklight and MFP.

Worklight 5.0 - Jan 11, 2013
Worklight 6.0 - Jul 19, 2013
Worklight 6.1 - Dec 13, 2013
Worklight 6.2 - Jul 11, 2014
MFP 6.3 - Dec 12, 2014
MFP 7.0 - Mar 03, 2015
MFP 7.1 - Aug 18, 2015

Normally, IBM supports each products for 5 years.
So, go for the latest, which is better. More reliable and more features.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming your project, build and name it back to the original and run. This gives good results in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by setting up a new workspace.